# SQL Query to get value of recent order alongwith data from other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, sql-order-by

I am writing an SQL query to get data from more than 3 tables, but for simplifying the question here I am using a similar scenario with 3 tables.

Table1 **Customer (PK-CustomerID, Name)**

| CustomerID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Tina |
| 3 | Sam |

Table2 **Sales (FK-Id, SalePrice)**

| ID | SalePrice |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 200.00 |
| 2 | 300.00 |
| 3 | 400.00 |

Table3 **Order (PK-Id, FK-CustomerID, Date, Amount)**

| Id | CustomerID | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 25-09-2021 | 30.0 |
| 102 | 1 | 27-09-2021 | 40.0 |
| 103 | 2 | 19-09-2021 | 60.0 |

In the output, Date and Amount should be the from most recent Order (latest Date), for a customer

My approach was

```
    Select c.CustomerID, c.Name, s.SalePrice, RecentOrder.Date, RecentOrder.Amount from 
    Customer as c
    LEFT JOIN Sales s ON c.CustomerID = s.ID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT top 1 o.Date, o.Amount, o.CustomerID  
    FROM Order o, Customer c1 WHERE c1.CustomerID = o.CustomerID ORDER BY o.Date DESC) 
    RecentOrder ON c.CustomerID = RecentOrder.CustomerID
```

Output I get

**CustomerID, Name, SalePrice, Date, Amount**

| CustomerID | Name | SalePrice | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 200.00 | 27-09-2021 | 40.0 |
| 2 | Tina | 300.00 | null | null |
| 3 | Sam | 400.00 | null | null |

The output I get includes the most recent order out of all the orders. But I want to get the recent order out of the orders made by that customer

Output Required

**CustomerID, Name, SalePrice, Date, Amount**

| CustomerID | Name | SalePrice | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 200.00 | 27-09-2021 | 40.0 |
| 2 | Tina | 300.00 | 19-09-2021 | 60.0 |
| 3 | Sam | 400.00 | null | null |

Comment: Probably time to ditch that 30-year-old deprecated syntax! Your query should also produce an error with a table named `order` - it should be `[order]` - however that's totally avoidable by calling it `orders` - presumably it contains more than a single order?

Comment: Some people prefer to give object names "singleton" names, @Stu , so the problem is really the fact it's a reserved keyword. Perhaps  `CustomerOrder` would be a better choice if the OP wants a singleton name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of subquery in left join, you can check with outer apply.

Check following way

```sql
Select c.CustomerID, c.Name, s.SalePrice, RecentOrder.Date, RecentOrder.Amount 
from Customer c
LEFT JOIN Sales s ON c.CustomerID = s.ID
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT top 1 o.Date, o.Amount, o.CustomerID  
FROM [Order] o 
WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID ORDER BY o.Date DESC) RecentOrder`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pre-aggregate or identify the most recent order for *each* customer order, your query is selecting 1 row for *all* orders.

Try the following (untested!)

```
select c.CustomerID, c.Name, s.SalePrice, o.Date, o.Amount 
from Customer c
left join Sales s on c.CustomerID = s.ID
outer apply (
    select top (1) date, amount
    from [order] o
    where o.CustomerId=c.CustomerId
    order by Id desc
)o
```